# Setting up formatters in Neovim with mason & lsp-zero

Tags: lua, neovim

I am using lsp-zero & mason to install LSPs, formatters and linters. However, I am not sure how the formatters work and how can I configure them.

For example, the formatter for `yml` files seems not to be working even though that I've installed `yamlls` and `yamlfmt`. On the other hand, Golang's formatter seems to be working just fine, when I save a `*.go` file, it will be automatically formatted.

How would you setup the YAML formatter in this case? Here is a snippet of my configuration:

**lsp.lua**

```lua
local lsp = require("lsp-zero")

lsp.preset("recommended")

-- Fix Undefined global 'vim'
lsp.nvim_workspace()

local cmp = require('cmp')
local cmp_select = {behavior = cmp.SelectBehavior.Select}
local cmp_mappings = lsp.defaults.cmp_mappings({
  ['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(cmp_select),
  ['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(cmp_select),
  ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
  ["<C-Space>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
})

cmp_mappings['<Tab>'] = nil
cmp_mappings['<S-Tab>'] = nil

lsp.setup_nvim_cmp({
  mapping = cmp_mappings
})

lsp.set_preferences({
    suggest_lsp_servers = false,
    sign_icons = {
        error = 'E',
        warn = 'W',
        hint = 'H',
        info = 'I'
    }
})

lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}

  vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", function() vim.lsp.buf.definition() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "K", function() vim.lsp.buf.hover() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vws", function() vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vd", function() vim.diagnostic.open_float() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "[d", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_next() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "]d", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_prev() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vca", function() vim.lsp.buf.code_action() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vrr", function() vim.lsp.buf.references() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vrn", function() vim.lsp.buf.rename() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("i", "<C-h>", function() vim.lsp.buf.signature_help() end, opts)
end)

vim.diagnostic.config({
    virtual_text = true
})
```

**mason.lua**

```lua
require('mason-tool-installer').setup {
  ensure_installed = {
    'golangci-lint',
    'bash-language-server',
    'lua-language-server',
    'vim-language-server',
    'gopls',
    'stylua',
    'shellcheck',
    'sqlfmt',
    'editorconfig-checker',
    'gofumpt',
    'golines',
    'gomodifytags',
    'gotests',
    'goimports',
    'impl',
    'json-to-struct',
    'jq',
    'misspell',
    'revive',
    'shellcheck',
    'shfmt',
    'staticcheck',
    'vint',
    'yamllint',
    'yamlfmt',
    'yamlls',
    'hadolint',
    'dockerls',
    'diagnosticls',
    'sqlls',
    'terraformls',
    'delve'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mason is a package manager that allows you to *manage* packages. Some packages will work out of the box, others require manual set up and/or calling the required functionality via commands---formatters are one example of this.

Once you've installed the formatter via Mason, you can set up a Neovim auto-command that calls the formatter on particular files with desired arguments. For example, for `yamlfmt`, you can create a file (e.g. `~/.config/nvim/lua/autocmds.lua`) and add the following code:

```lua
-- Create group to assign commands
-- "clear = true" must be set to prevent loading an
-- auto-command repeatedly every time a file is resourced
local autocmd_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("Custom auto-commands", { clear = true })

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufWritePost" }, {
    pattern = { "*.yaml", "*.yml" },
    desc = "Auto-format YAML files after saving",
    callback = function()
        local fileName = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
        vim.cmd(":!yamlfmt " .. fileName)
    end,
    group = autocmd_group,
})
```

Then, ensure this file (`autocmds.lua`) is sourced every time you start Neovim by  adding `require("autocmds")` to your `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` file.

Now, every time you write a buffer (`BufWritePost`) (i.e. save a file) ending with a `.yaml` or `.yml` extension, the callback will be made which gets the absolute path of the file loaded in the current buffer (`nvim_buf_get_name(0)`), and then executes a non-interactive terminal command that calls the YAML formatter on that file.

To suppress the command's output, you add `silent` to the non-interactive terminal command:

```lua
vim.cmd(":silent !yamlfmt " .. fileName)
```

You can also add multiple terminal commands to the callback. For example, when editing my Python files, I call the following formatters, each of which handles a specific part of code:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufWritePost" }, {
    pattern = { "*.py" },
    desc = "Auto-format Python files after saving",
    callback = function()
        local fileName = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
        vim.cmd(":silent !black --preview -q " .. fileName)
        vim.cmd(":silent !isort --profile black --float-to-top -q " .. fileName)
        vim.cmd(":silent !docformatter --in-place --black " .. fileName)
    end,
    group = autocmd_group,
})
```

Don't forget to add each auto-command to an auto-command group that has the `clear` flag set to avoid repeatedly loading a command every time a file is resourced. You can read more about auto-commands via the manual `:h autocmd`.